# Is LanguageTool free if I host my own server?

Tags: languagetool

https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool

Based on their documentation, they allow us to host our own server but I'm wondering if there's any request restriction or is it completely free to use? I know their public server has request limitation and offers paid service but I'm not sure if it goes the same for when hosting our own server.

Answer (score 1):

The self-hosted version of LanguageTool has no restrictions on the number of requests, since it runs "[offline](https://dev.languagetool.org/http-server)" locally. Offline is in the sense of that it does not use the LanguageTool [public HTTP API](https://dev.languagetool.org/public-http-api) that has these restrictions.